# jQuery change class of td based on next elemt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table output that might look like this:

```
<tr class="parent" id="someunique1">
<td class="more">IP</td>
<td>blabla</td><td>131313</td><td>04.04.2014, 22:51:02</td>
<td class="redtr">Yup</td>
</tr>

<tr class="parent" id="someunique2">
<td class="more">IP</td>
<td>blaabla</td><td>blarblar</td><td>04.04.2014, 11:33:47</td>
<td>Nope</td>
</tr>

<tr class="child">
```

Using jQuery, how could I remove the class "more" from the first td under the first parent tr, if the next tr class is another parent?

In the example above I want to keep "more" as a class for the second tr, but not the first, since it's followed bu another parent tr.

Any help appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('.parent + .parent').prev().find('td.more').removeClass('more')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PWDgR/)

- [Next Adjacent Selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/)

Comment: Wow! that was short and sweet. Thank you!

Comment: I don't expect you to bother with this, but how would I tweak it to also include removing the class if next after the .parent tr is the closing </table>?

Comment: @WebandAvec try `$('.parent + .parent, .parent:last-child').prev().find('td.more').removeClass('more')`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. It didn't do it I'm afraid.

Comment: That is awesome! I have a long way to go when it comes to jQuery/JS. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
$('#someunique1').children().removeClass('more');
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4yr4R/1/

Comment: Thanks for helping, this was not quite what I was looking for. Appreciate time used though.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('tr.parent').each(function() {
    if($(this).next('tr').find('.more').length > 0) {
        $(this).find('.more').removeClass('more');        
    }
});
```

This will loop through every `tr` with class `parent` and if the next `tr` contains an element with the class `more` it will remove the class from the element with the class `more` inside the current `tr` but not from the second since it'll have some other tr as the next one

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/z33ex/) :

```
$('tr').each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(this).next('tr').hasClass('parent')) {
         $(this).find('.more').removeClass('more');   
    }
});
```

For each `tr`, we check if the next `tr` own the `parent` class, and if so, we just remove the `more` class in its child.